# why does my for loop only work on the first element?

Tags: javascript

I stumbled upon a problem that i have no idea how to fix. I want to be able to check when a radio button is checked. If one of the five buttons is checked, it should give the feedback. Somehow with my code, when i check the first radio button, it works. But if i check the 2nd or 3rd ... It gives me the alert message: please give a rating. So that means either the for loop in the function radioChecker is not working as intended, or i don't know.

```
{
let validation = document.querySelector('.type__style');
let validation2 = document.getElementById("label__text");

const init = () => {
    const $button = document.getElementById('send__button');
    $button.onclick = () => {
        revealText();
        setTimeout(dissapearText, 4000);

    }

const radioChecker = () => {
    let radios = document.querySelector(".stars").querySelectorAll("input");
    for (let i = 0; i <radios.length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked) {
            console.log("yes");
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

    const revealText = () => {


        if (validation.value === "") {
            validation.focus();
            window.alert("Please enter your name.");
            return false;
        } else if (validation2.value === "") {
            validation2.focus();
            window.alert("Please fill in commentary.");
            return false;
        } else if (radioChecker() === false) {
            window.alert("Please give a rating.");
            return false;

        } else {
            document.querySelector('.feedback').style.opacity = 1;
            console.log('work');
            return true;
        }

    }

    const dissapearText = () => {
        document.querySelector('.feedback').style.opacity = 0;
    }




}
init();
```

}

Comment: You're `return`ing every loop, it will never progress past the first iteration.

Comment: Because you immediately `return` from the function in the first iteration.

Comment: The `return` statement is an instruction to immediately exit a function.

Comment: Remove the `else` condition from the loop and add a `return false` after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const radioChecker = () => {
    let radios = document.querySelector(".stars").querySelectorAll("input");
    for (let i = 0; i <radios.length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked) {
            console.log("yes");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Explanation:
So, the for loop check all `radios`. if any radio is checked, it will immediately `return true`.
After running full loop, if it did not find any radio is checked, it will `return false`.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have a `return true` in the loop. The moment it returns true on the first loop it will break the loop.

Comment: sorry if i'm still making dumb mistakes since i'm really new to js. I removed the return true but it's still not functioning as intended.

Comment: no problem, hey we all had issues like this at one time